# Set Paper Size in the ReportViewer 2008

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer2008

in vb.net 2008 add in MSReport 2008

I am facing a serious problem while Set & Get the Page Margin, Paper Size, Orientation etc to & from the RDLC - Report Viewer Page  Setting  dialog.

I want to do this in Programmatically.

Note :

1. Programmatically I can able to get the default values of Page Margins from the PageSettings.
2. Once I change the values in the PageSettings, I **cannot** able to retrieve the modified PageSettings values, it fetches only the default values of the PageSettings.

ex.,

Following code gets the default value

```
<code>
MarginTop = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
MarginLeft = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
MarginRight = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right
MarginBottom = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottomenter 
</code>
```

Kindly help me to Get & Set the PageSettings values Dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure the report *viewer* doesn't handle page settings, and it has to be done in the report definition itself. Someone back me up?